How to enable jemalloc's memory profiling by default?
It is recommended to set MALLOC_CONF before running a certain program.
However, I does not always have access to how the program is started.
So I found the --with-jemalloc-prefix option in jemalloc's document. Seems that we could pre-define the configuration when building the program.
However, I don'w how this could cowork with cmake. For example, the following will cause a definition of macro of --with-jemalloc-prefix
target_compile_definitions (jemalloc PRIVATE --with-jemalloc-prefix="prof:true,prof_active:true,lg_prof_interval:10")


That compile option is for the jemalloc build system (configure-based), not yours. You need to compile jemalloc yourself. The documentation also mentions an /etc/malloc.conf, which seems like it suits your usecase.
